# Memcpy string as void pointer, incorrect read

Tags: c, pointers, buffer, memcpy

I'm trying to create a function that puts together a buffer from arbitrary types. Think basic RPC. So the buffer looks something like

```
{ char opcode, uint32_t param1_size, param1, ... , uint32_t paramN_size, paramN }
```

It seems to be working but when extracting the data from the buffer it doesn't seem to be interpreting the string correctly.

```
int enqueue_into_buf(char *buf, size_t buf_pos, const uint32_t param_len, const void *param) {

    /* If param_len is NULL, then change opcode */
    if(param_len == 0) {
        memcpy( buf, param, 1 );
        if(buf_pos == 0)
            buf_pos++;
        return buf_pos;
    }

    memcpy( buf + buf_pos, &param_len, sizeof(param_len) );
    buf_pos += sizeof(param_len);

    memcpy( buf + buf_pos, param, param_len );
    buf_pos += param_len;

    return buf_pos;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char opcode;
    uint32_t param_len, num_params, buf_size, buf_pos = 0, received_num;
    char *buf, *temp;

    char *input_string = "file01"; /* example string to use as parameter */
    size_t input_size = 4, received_size; /* example variable to also use as a parameter */

    opcode = '1'; /* opcode equals function 1 */
    num_params = 2; /* number of parameters */

    /* setting the size of the buffer that will be sent over the network */
    buf_size = sizeof(opcode) + ( num_params * sizeof(uint32_t) ) + (strlen(input_string) * sizeof(char)) + sizeof(input_size);
    buf = malloc( buf_size );

    /* Notice the ampersand! */
    buf_pos = enqueue_into_buf(buf, buf_pos, 0, &opcode);
    buf_pos = enqueue_into_buf(buf, buf_pos, strlen(input_string), &input_string);
    buf_pos = enqueue_into_buf(buf, buf_pos, sizeof(input_size), &input_size);

    /* At this point, since we inserted everything into the buffer, 
    the buffer size and current buffer position should be equal */ 
    if(buf_pos == buf_size)
        printf("Calculated buffer size correctly and inserted everything correctly as well. Buffer size = %d\n", buf_size);

    /** Extract from buffer **/
    buf_pos = 0;

    printf("Opcode: %c\n", buf[buf_pos]);
    buf_pos++;

    memcpy(&received_num, buf + buf_pos, sizeof(uint32_t));
    printf("Size of parameter 1: %d\n", received_num);
    buf_pos += sizeof(uint32_t);

    temp = malloc(received_num + 1);
    memcpy(temp, buf + buf_pos, received_num);
    temp[received_num] = '\0';
    printf("Parameter 1: %s\n", temp);
    buf_pos += received_num;

    memcpy(&received_num, buf + buf_pos, sizeof(uint32_t));
    printf("Size of parameter 2: %d\n", received_num);
    buf_pos += sizeof(uint32_t);

    memcpy(&received_size, buf + buf_pos, sizeof(size_t));
    printf("Parameter 2: %d\n", received_size);
    buf_pos += sizeof(size_t);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Output of code:

```
Calculated buffer size correctly and inserted everything correctly as well. Buffer size = 23
Opcode: 1
Size of parameter 1: 6
Parameter 1: @  @
Size of parameter 2: 8
Parameter 2: 4
```

I think I'm not copying the data correctly into the buffer because, using the same parameters (input_string = "file01", input_size = 4), this code works...

```
    /* OPCODE */
    buf[buf_pos] = opcode;
    buf_pos++;

    /* PARAMETER 1 */
    param_len = (strlen(input_string) * sizeof(char)); /* size of parameter 1 */

    memcpy(buf + buf_pos, &param_len, sizeof(uint32_t));
    buf_pos += sizeof(uint32_t);

    //memcpy( buf + buf_pos, &input_string, (strlen(input_string) * sizeof(char)) );
    strcat( buf + buf_pos, input_string );
    buf_pos += strlen(input_string) * sizeof(char);


    /* PARAMETER 2 */
    param_len = sizeof(input_size);

    memcpy(buf + buf_pos, &param_len, sizeof(param_len)); /* same as saying sizeof(uint32_t) */
    buf_pos += sizeof(uint32_t);

    memcpy(buf + buf_pos, &input_size, sizeof(input_size));
    buf_pos += sizeof(input_size);
```

EDIT: Output of code:

```
Calculated buffer size correctly and inserted everything correctly as well. Buffer size = 23
Opcode: 1
Size of parameter 1: 6
Parameter 1: file01
Size of parameter 2: 8
Parameter 2: 4
```

But obviously I don't want to use strcat() because I won't know what kind of data type it will be. Am I using memcpy incorrectly??

EDIT: put outputs of programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You highlighted the problem yourself:

```
/* Notice the ampersand! */
buf_pos = enqueue_into_buf(buf, buf_pos, 0, &opcode);
buf_pos = enqueue_into_buf(buf, buf_pos, strlen(input_string), &input_string);
```

You have declared

```
char *input_string = "file01";
```

So when you pass `&input_string` to `enqueue_into_buf`, you are copying `strlen(input_string)` bytes starting from where the pointer `input_string` is stored into the buffer.

Usually, on 64-bit systems, that would be six of the eight bytes of the pointer value, on 32-bit systems the four bytes of the pointer plus two behind that (invoking undefined behaviour).

But you want to copy the string `"file01"` to the buffer, i.e. what the pointer points to, hence you must not pass the address of the pointer but the pointer itself:

```
buf_pos = enqueue_into_buf(buf, buf_pos, strlen(input_string), input_string);
                                                           // ^^ No address taken here!
```

Comment: Makes sense; mad I made the mistake. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here.

First:

```
buf_pos = enqueue_into_buf(buf, buf_pos, strlen(input_string), &input_string);
```

You're trying to pass the fourth parameter to enque as a `void *` well a string is already a pointer type, so passing the address of the string is *not* what you wanted to do, just:

```
buf_pos = enqueue_into_buf(buf, buf_pos, strlen(input_string), input_string);
```

Is correct.

Second:

You never zero'ed out your buf, so you don't know what is sitting in there:

```
buf = malloc( buf_size );
memset(buf, 0, buf_size);  // add this line here to clear the buffer before using it
```

Declare, allocate, initialize... then use. It will save you a lot of headaches.